# Incorrect result when select count distinct with order by and math function in MySQL 5.7.17

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a simple table named `temp` with three columns and the following data:

```
# c1  c2  v
  1   1  'a'
  1   2  'b'
  1   1  'b'
  1   2  'a'
```

I run the query:

```
SELECT
    t01.c1,
    t01.c2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        FLOOR(c1) AS c1,
        FLOOR(c2) AS c2,
        v
    FROM 
        temp
)   AS t01
GROUP BY
    t01.c1,
    t01.c2
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC
```

This should return the following:

```
# c1, c2, cnt
   1,  1,  2
   1,  2,  2
```

But actually it returns this:

```
# c1, c2, cnt
   1,  1,  1
   1,  2,  1
   1,  1,  1
   1,  2,  1
```

This is strange just  when it contains math function **floor** **order by**  **group by** **count distinct** and the result is **incorrect** - it does not group the data.

Is this a MySQL bug in version 5.7.17?

Comment: Your question is too long.  Please ask your question using just one, or maybe two, queries.

Comment: It works without the `order by`. This is weird.

Comment: That `Floor()` in the subquery seems 100% superfluous without a `GROUP BY v` included in the subquery as well. Perhaps the oddball results you are getting is due to the exclusion of that group by in your subquery?

Comment: @JNevill: The query itself is eligible. It should work but it doesn't.

Comment: @juergend Yes... I see that now. For some reason this morning I was thinking that FLOOR() is aggregate, but obviously it's just a mathematical function like ABS(). Feels like a bug.

Comment: Please post the table definition as the column types may be important. And the insert statements so I can set it up correctly here.  Considered setting up an SQLFiddle?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

Comment: File a bug with http://bugs.mysql.com Point out that it seems to be a regression in 5.7.  Post the bug number here.

Comment: Does it work if you leave out floor()?
If it does, are both c1 and c2 integer columns? 
If they are, the older version might ignore the floor() function since the data is already integer.

Comment: looks like this is your issue https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80310

Comment: As this is probably a bug I found a very simple way to get your result, see my answer.

Comment: Bug#80310 was fixed in 5.7.18.  I am able to reproduce the problem on 5.7.19.  Hence, it is not the same bug.

Comment: @william  please check this if we need expected output, we can also use this:  `select c1,c2,count(1) from temp group by c1,c2 order by count(1) desc;`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is a bug related to merging the derived table (subquery in `FROM` clause) into the outer query. Please, file a bug at [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com).

**Workarounds:**

- Set `optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';`
- Add a `LIMIT` clause to the subquery.  That will be prevent it from being merged into the outer query.
- Manually merge the subquery with the outer query:

---

```
SELECT 
  FLOOR(c1) AS g1, 
  FLOOR(c2) AS g2, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT v) AS cnt   
FROM temp
GROUP BY g1, g2
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

It just tried it in MySql 5.6 on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad9aa8/1/0)  and it just works. And on 
[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=4kqdAsoIVb) in MySql 5.7 it doesn't.

So it's probably something with MySql 5.7 as you already thought.

According to [MySql reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html) under (Features Deprecated in MySQL 5.7)

> GROUP BY implicitly sorts by default (that is, in the absence of ASC
>   or DESC designators), but relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting in
>   MySQL 5.7 is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped
>   results, it is preferable to use To produce a given sort order, use
>   explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns or provide an
>   ORDER BY clause. GROUP BY sorting is a MySQL extension that may change
>   in a future release; for example, to make it possible for the
>   optimizer to order groupings in whatever manner it deems most
>   efficient and to avoid the sorting overhead.

---

**Update**:

I tried something else for you which works:

```
SELECT
    t01.c1,
    t01.c2,
    count(v) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT v as v,
        FLOOR(c1) AS c1,
        FLOOR(c2) AS c2

    FROM 
        temp
)   AS t01
GROUP BY
    t01.c1,
    t01.c2
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC
```

This is my create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    (`c1` int, `c2` int, `v` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO temp
    (`c1`, `c2`, `v`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '''a'''),
    (1, 1, '''a'''),
    (1, 2, '''b'''),
    (1, 1, '''b'''),
    (1, 1, '''c'''),
    (1, 2, '''a''')
;
```

the result:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7zBFKzd3pE7ymrD5LTcmkz/1

Comment: That doc reference only explains that for a garanteed order you need to define a `order by` clause. So I think it is not relevant. Or do you?

Comment: Yes I think it's relevant, because it's a change in exactly the part where the problem is described. And also the group by now sorts by default (which also explains why without the sort it works)

Comment: *group by now sorts by default (which also explains why without the sort it works)* - I don't aggree here but we'll see what the community thinks about it.

Comment: What I mean is that they changed something here, this could result in a bug

Comment: Note that the implicit sorting is deprecated, not removed.  (It is removed in 8.0.)   Anyway, implicit sorting does not apply here since there is an (explicit) ORDER BY clause.